# How to use a non-npm node_module in meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I just forked a node module and fixed some of its problems. The originally version was referenced in my Meteor project using `Npm.depends`. But now I want to use my forked version instead (until the original owner accepts my pull request).

What's a good way of doing this? I don't really want to publish my forked version onto npmjs.org.

Is it possible to use Npm.depends on git urls?

Comment: you can upload to npm with a different name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick hack I came up with :

I have my custom node module located in MyProject/packages/my-package/my-node-module
(you'll need to git clone your forked node module locally)

In the main.js file of your package, you can reference your node module using Npm.require like this :

```
console.log(process.cwd());
// this will output something like "/home/user/projects/MyProject/.meteor/local/build/programs/server"
var myNodeModule=Npm.require("../../../../../packages/my-package/my-node-module");
```

We use the parent directory syntax to get back to the project directory, then reference the relative path of our node module.

We don't need Npm.depends using this technique, it's not very nice but it will do the trick.

Comment: Does this still work after you've bundled an app? This solution is vulnerable to breaking if and when there are to changes to the Meteor project structure in future versions.

Comment: If I remember well it won't work after bundling, but you can still use an absolute path, which is even more hacky but it can be handy.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily wrap it in a smart package, no hacking required.

I had the same problem when I came across a useful, abandoned module that had a couple of bugs in it. I forked the module and wrapped it in a smart package. Example:

[Smart Package](https://github.com/davidworkman9/s3Policies) my fork of the [npm module](https://github.com/davidworkman9/s3policy)